# Show project path in Xcode windows

Tags: xcode

Is there any way to set a preference in Xcode to show the project's full path in the title bar, or status bar?

I work on multiple copies of the same project at the same time, and it's really annoying to try to remember which window is which.  Currently I have to check the properties of a file in the project to figure out which one I'm working on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with most Mac OS X windows, <kbd>Command</kbd>-click on the title will show you the path.

Comment: I guess that's better than nothing.  Not really what I'm looking for, but I guess Apple knows better than me how I want to work... like always.

Answer (score 4):

As of Yosemite the closest thing to control-clicking the title bar (which is no longer possible) is to right-click the file name in the jump menu at the top of your project window in Xcode.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I work on multiple copies of the same project at the same time, and it's really annoying to try to remember which window is which.

I have the same problem, I use the file inspector to see the full path

[image]